# Add on domain mod rewrite to create pretty url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, dns

I have a main website www.site.co.uk and one of my add on domains is addon.co.uk. Site has an htaccess as does addon. The folder of which from the root would be www.site.co.uk/addon.co.uk/.htaccess ..I think!

Anyway currently I can do redirects within addon htaccess file fine, but its a database driven site and im trying to create pretty urls for it, so:

http://www.addon.co.uk/addonsites/some.php?id=page

would become:

http://www.addon.co.uk/id/page/

The mod I have in the addon htaccess file is the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^id/([^/]*)/$ /addonsites/some.php?id=$1 [L]
```

But this has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the `mod_rewrite` module will perform translations on *requests **to** the server*, so when anyone requests the resource located at `http://www.addon.co.uk/id/page/` the server will know that `http://www.addon.co.uk/addonsites/some.php?id=page` is the place to go.

However, `mod_rewrite` does *in no way* modify your existing links. I.e., *you* should rewrite the HTML (or scripts generating the HTML) to match the "new" way of linking. E.g., if you have `<a href="/addonsites/some.php?id=page">...</a>` somewhere on your site, you must make sure it is changed to `<a href="/id/page/">...</a>`.

**tl;dr**
`mod_rewrite` handles incoming requests; it does not modify your output (HTML).